# Best practices for securely using Google Maps API keys

Tags: javascript, php, api, maps

Google recommends not exposing an API number. Fair enough, even if they ask in most of working examples to include your API key in the code

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Then you get this recommendation seen at: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037 - **Do not embed API keys directly in code!**

So my question is how do I securely embed Google Map API Key, making it in the same time invisible to other users?
I use PHP, JS and MySQL

Comment: That's a good question because urls can be logged and through their doc i can't find if you could include it as a header.

Comment: Since the languages you mention suggest website rather than installed app, just set a domain whitelist in google console and forget about it.

Comment: I'm going to to that, is just i was actually wandering what could be a solution for this?